# Arelle Xbrl validation - unable to start web service - socket error 10013

Tags: python, web-services, iis, arelle

I'm using the Arelle project to implement validation of my Xbrl files.

http://arelle.org/documentation/api-web-services/

When i try to start the webserver that i can call from my code i receive following error.
Been looking up how to fix this and it all points to disabling my antivirus. Got it disabled and i still get this error. Arelle is a Python project

This should start a webservice that i can reach on www.localhost:8082/rest/xbrl

[image: Webservice startup error]

Answer (score 0):

Appearently this was an issue with the previous release of the project.

I installed the latest version 2013-07-25 and no longer had this socket error